# Can not display inline form inside ul

Tags: html, css

I have a ul list with normal text inside the li tag. I tried to display it inline and it worked.

However, I tried to replace that text with a form, then it could not be displayed inline anymore.

Here is my html:

```
<ul class='test'>
   <li><form method='post' action=''>
       <input type='hidden'><br><br>
       <button class='hi' type='submit'>Test1</button>
       </form>
  </li>
  <li><form method='post' action=''>
     <input type='hidden'><br><br>
     <button class='hi' type='submit'>Test2</button>
     </form>
  </li>
```

Here is css for that:

```
.hi{
  display:block;
  background-color:white;
  color:blue;
  border: none;
  outline:none;
}
.hi:hover{
   text-decoration:underline;
}
.test{
  list-style-type:none
}
.test li{
  display:inline;
}
```

Here is my [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/giangvy1011/Lwr0t6ko/)

What should I do for the test 1 and test 2 in that jsfiddle to be displayed inline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default in browsers, `<form>` css is `display: block;`

You have to define in your css file,

```
form {
    display:inline;
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lwr0t6ko/1/)

The better way is define class in `<form>`

```
<form method="post" action="" class="myform">
```

and add in your css

```
.myform {
    display:inline;
}
```

It will over ride the default browser css and also will not effect the other forms you have or will have in website.

Answer (score 1):

Few problems: `br`created newline. `form` is default to `display:block`. Your `button` is set to `display:block`.

```
form, button.hi {
    display:inline;
}

br {
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you just add the tag

```
.test li {
  float:left;
  display:inline
}
```